# Deserialize JSON object that has no name

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

We have a rather odd JSON payload that needs to be deserialized, but I'm unsure how to go about doing it with Java and Gson.

```
{ 
  "Red": {
           "Level 1": "Specify Action",
           "Level 2": "Action Taken",
           "Level 3": "No Action Taken"
  },
  "Orange": {
           "Level 4": "Defeat Gannon",
           "Level 5": "Save Princess",
           "Level 6": "Find Triforce"
  }
}
```

We can use a HashMap to deserialize the individual objects (i.e. "Red" and "Orange"), but the problem we're having is trying to account for the parent object, which, as the code shows, has no name to easily hook into.

Comment: How are you passing this payload around in your HashMap function if it doesn't have a variable name?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've only figured out I could use a HashMap to represent the "Red" and "Orange" objects, but as you pointed out, I'm unable to pass the overall payload since I'm unsure how to reference the parent object.

Comment: what do you mean by parent object.?

Comment: The first line of the payload does not contain a variable name. It's just an opening bracket, "{". Ideally, I wish the payload looked like this...

{ "Colors": "Red": {
           "Level 1": "Specify Action",
           "Level 2": "Action Taken",
           "Level 3": "No Action Taken"
  },
  "Orange": {
           "Level 4": "Defeat Gannon",
           "Level 5": "Save Princess",
           "Level 6": "Find Triforce"
  }
}

Comment: What is producing this JSON? A human testing your program, etc?

Comment: Not sure about Gson, but using org.json, you would use JSONObject j = new JSONObject("{json string here}");  JSONObject red = j.getJSONObject("Red");

Comment: The first line of the payload does not contain a variable name. It's just an opening bracket, "{". Ideally, I wish the payload looked like this...

{ "Colors": 
    {
      "Red": {
           "Level 1": "Specify Action",
           "Level 2": "Action Taken",
           "Level 3": "No Action Taken"
  }
},
   {
     "Orange": {
           "Level 4": "Defeat Gannon",
           "Level 5": "Save Princess",
           "Level 6": "Find Triforce"
      }
   }
}

But I don't have a "Colors" variable name, so unsure what my starting point should be.

Comment: @Alex A...it's a backend system, so unfortunately, we have no control over its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your JSON looks like below:

```
{
    "Red": {
       "Level 1": "Specify Action",
       "Level 2": "Action Taken",
       "Level 3": "No Action Taken"
    },
   "Orange": {
       "Level 4": "Defeat Gannon",
       "Level 5": "Save Princess",
       "Level 6": "Find Triforce"
     }
}
```

I will use HashMap, something like below with Jackson API. I think similar can be done using GSON as well

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

        public class Test {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String jsonInString = "{\n" +
                        "    \"Red\": {\n" +
                        "        \"Level 1\": \"Specify Action\",\n" +
                        "        \"Level 2\": \"Action Taken\",\n" +
                        "        \"Level 3\": \"No Action Taken\"\n" +
                        "    },\n" +
                        "    \"Orange\": {\n" +
                        "        \"Level 4\": \"Defeat Gannon\",\n" +
                        "        \"Level 5\": \"Save Princess\",\n" +
                        "        \"Level 6\": \"Find Triforce\"\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "}";

                TypeReference< Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>> typeRef
                        = new TypeReference<Map<String, HashMap<String, String>>>() {
                };

                Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> value = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, typeRef);

                System.out.println(value);

            }
        }
```